# ar package for Aspect Ratio symbol

Tags: symbols, packages, installing

I try to get the Aspect Ratio Symbol used in aeronautics (A and R together see p.78 of [this document](ftp://tug.ctan.org/pub/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf)) but it requires the `ar` package. I call `\usepackage{ar}` in my code and get the error: file `ar.sty` not found.

I already tried to install it under Windows some month ago (didn't manage it) but now I'm running Ubuntu so I hope I'll find someone who knows how to fix this. I would also accept a solution using another package as long as it produces this symbol (but I haven't been able to find one so far).

Comment: under ubuntu all you need to do is install the `texlive-fonts-extra` package, using synaptic or apt-get.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply put [`ar.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/ar/ar.sty) package in your working directory. Here is it's code:

```
%
% This package is for using the aspect ratio symbol in math mode and in
% text mode by means of the command \AR.
%
% It is supposed to work both with LaTeX209 and LaTeXe
% It requires the METAFONT files ar5.mf, ar6.mf, ar7.mf, ar8.mf, ar9.mf,
%                                ar10.mf, ar12.mf
%
\ifx\documentclass\undefined
% With LaTeX209 the symbol is available in just one size (by default)
% but the user can edit the next line in order to get the size s/he wants
  \newfont{\ar}{ar10 at 10pt}
  \load{\normalsize}{\ar}
  \def\AR{\mbox{\ar A}}
\else
% While with LaTeXe all standard sizes are available 
% (no bold version available...sorry!) 
  \DeclareFontFamily{U}{ar}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{ar}{m}{it}%
       {<5><6><7><8><9>gen*ar%
        <10><10.95>ar10%
        <12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>ar12%
        }{}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{ar}{b}{it}%
     {<->ssub*ar/m/it}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{ar}{bx}{it}%
     {<->ssub*ar/m/it}{}
  \DeclareMathAlphabet{\mar}{U}{ar}{m}{it}%
  \SetMathAlphabet{\mar}{normal}{U}{ar}{m}{it}%
  \SetMathAlphabet{\mar}{bold}{U}{ar}{bx}{it}% actually uses medium series
  \if@compatibility
   \def\tar{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{ar}\itshape}
   \DeclareRobustCommand{\ar}{\ifmmode\let\cf@ar\mar\else\let\cf@ar\tar\fi\cf@ar}
  \else
   \DeclareOldFontCommand{\ar}{\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{ar}\itshape}{\mar}%
  \fi
  \DeclareRobustCommand{\AR}{{\ar A}}
\fi
\endinput
```

Then you have to make sure that you have at least the [`ar10.mf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/obsolete/macros/latex/contrib/ar/ar10.mf) file in the same directory.

And if you want all the sizes, use the files from [this repository](http://ctan.org/pkg/ar/).

Comment: If you are running Linux the simplest way to use the `ar` package is to run the command `sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra` and that should do the work for you.

Answer (score 9):

Based on David Carlisle’s answer and some experimentation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{trimclip}

\begin{document}

\def\AR{\clipbox{0pt 0pt .32em 0pt}\AE\kern-.30emR}

              A\AE \AR R
\large        A\AE \AR R
\footnotesize A\AE \AR R

\itshape      A\AE \AR R
\large        A\AE \AR R
\footnotesize A\AE \AR R

\end{document}
```

Yields this result, which I think is pretty close to what the [`ar`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ar) and [`aspectratio`](http://ctan.org/pkg/aspectratio) packages provide:

[image]

**Edit:** Since this symbol will be used in math mode, and is apparently always italicised, use this definition instead (requires `amsmath`):

```
\def\AR{\text{\itshape\clipbox{0pt 0pt .32em 0pt}\AE\kern-.30emR}}
```

Comment: Very nice solution which does what I was looking for. However, in my case, I found a way around running the appropriate command in a terminal to install easily the `ar` package (`sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra`). That is a little bit overkilled to install all the extra fonts for only this symbol but actually a lot of them might turn useful.

Comment: A pirate goes into a bar......

Answer (score 4):

Using a metafont font for just one symbol might be considered excessive these days, and the generated bitmaps won't work too well in pdf viewers. An alternative would be to just bump an A and R together:

[image]

You can fine tune the spacing a bit more, especially if you are using a different base font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{trimclip}

\begin{document}



\def\AR{\clipbox{0pt 0pt .35em 0pt}{\textit{\bfseries A}}\kern-.05emR}

\AR  \large \AR \footnotesize \AR


\end{document}
```

An alternative suggested in the comments is

```
\def\AR{\clipbox{0pt 0pt .35em 0pt}{\textit{\bfseries \AE}}\kern-.4em\textit{\bfseries R}}
```

Comment: Nice solution quite light and handy but I am really looking for the symbol as presented in the link of the question.

Comment: @LudovicC. OK then no problem to accept the other answer:-) but remember it is a bitmap font so won't look so nice in pdf:-)

Comment: @LudovicC. What are you doing with `\textbf{\bfseries R}` exactly? Please ask the owner of the answer first before you edit it. It saves lots of trouble

Comment: Sorry it is a mistyping the command is actually `\textit{\bfseries R}` but as it is only a two caracters correction I cannot edit it. Sorry again!

Comment: @LudovicC. I rolled the edit back as it made the code and image not match, but added the `\AE` code as an alternative at the end.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, could you just correct the mistake in the "new" code by replacing the `\textbf` before the R by `\textit`?

Comment: @LudovicC. -- i fixed the code as you requested.